# Opencart-How can I display the flat rate in Delivery details section in Checkout

Tags: opencart

In opencart I added shipping flat rate 150 via admin panel. In Checkout `delivery details` section I wish to show the flat rate.

How can I display the flat rate in Delivery details section in Checkout? That is I want to display it in `catalog/view/theme/default/template/checkout/shipping_addres.tpl`.

My opencart version is 2.0.3.1.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution:

**$_SESSION** contain a set of values which help me to find the solution.

```
var_dump($_SESSION); //you can see all session values
```

`echo $_SESSION['shipping_methods']['flat']['quote']['flat']['text'];`
 gives the currency symbol and flat rate.

result is: **INR 150** or **EUR 2.01** or **USD 2.25** (depends your currency)

Any other answer(if any) are most welcome..